# Issue with running an external process and updating UI elements in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a C# application where I need to run an external process using `Process.Start()` and update UI elements based on the output of that process. However, I'm facing a weird problem where the UI update only happens once, even though the process is supposed to be executed multiple times.

**Code:**

```
private void pic()
{
    MessageBox.Show("just runs once?!");
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/ffmpeg.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i {"C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/New folder/video.mp4"} -vf \"select=eq(n\\,{master_frame})\" -vframes 1";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
        {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("output.jpg");
        }));
    }
}

private async void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    move = true;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (move)
        {
            pic();
            MessageBox.Show(master_frame.ToString()); // Runs multiple times one by one
            master_frame++;
        }
    });
}
```

**Issue:**

The issue I'm facing is that the pic() method, which executes an external process and updates a PictureBox control, is only being executed once. However, I expect it to run multiple times based on the while loop in the panel1_MouseUp event handler.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the pic() method to be called repeatedly within the while loop, executing the external process each time, and updating the PictureBox with the output image. Additionally, I expect the message box displaying the master_frame variable to show multiple times, incrementing its value with each iteration.

**Actual Behavior:**

Currently, the pic() method runs only once, and the UI update for the PictureBox control also happens only once. The message box, however, correctly shows multiple times, indicating that the loop is executing as expected.

**Additional Information:**

I have verified that the external process is executing correctly by manually running it outside of the application.
The file paths used in the code are correct, and the required files are present in the specified locations.
I have also confirmed that the panel1_MouseUp event is firing correctly when the mouse button is released.
Any help or insights on why the pic() method is not being called multiple times and why the UI update is not happening on each iteration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1) You need to wait for the process to exit before doing anything with the result. 2) Showing messageboxes from background threads is not a good idea. Use breakpoints if you need to debug. 3) Use a method parameters for the frame variable.

Comment: [Once again, I have to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76576523/pic-method-is-called-only-once-within-while-loop-how-to-make-it-execute-repe?noredirect=1#comment135014873_76576523): What happens when you *step through* `pic`? Does it exit normally and resume the loop? If not, where does it stop? What you call the "issue" is actually just the *symptom*.

Comment: Yes because another messagebox in the end of pic would show.

Comment: And what happens when you step through it the *next* time?

Comment: That's the problem, Nothing happens.

Comment: ***Details***. Which line does it stop at?

Comment: There is no stoping at all.

Comment: It has to stop if it only runs once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254303/discussion-between-frostdream-and-madreflection).

Comment: No. At this point, you need to use the debugger to observe what's happening and when it stops functioning as expected. I'm not going to hold your hand while you do that. Reposting the same question without providing the *debugging information* that was requested in the first place was a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any logic in this line `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("output.jpg")`.

When you don't write full path to the file like `"output.jpg"`, then application takes it from the working directory, in your case this is where the exe file of your program is. If it does not give you an error, then there is a file called `"output.jpg"`. I think the reason of your issue is that your process does not change it and it turns out that your pictureBox1 shows the same image every iteration.
Make sure you write the correct command for ffmpeg. Try it in the console if you get the correct result you will be sure that the problem is not in the command. I don't understand how to work with ffmpeg but your line "-i {videoPath} -vf "select=eq(n\,{master_frame})" -vframes 1" doesn't seem to work correctly. I tried it separately in console and got the error "At least one output file must be specified".

`PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\ffmpeg-2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-full_build\bin> .\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\Users\User\Downloads\Youre_God_damn_right.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,{5})" -vframes 1`

> At least one output file must be specified

I can also suggest you try following architecture(not sure if while loop can be stopped)

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RunProcessOnce();
    }

    private int master_frame = 0;

    private string ffmpegPath = @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\ffmpeg-2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
    private string videoPath = @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Youre_God_damn_right.mp4";
    private void RunProcessOnce()
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i {videoPath} -vf \"select=eq(n\\,{master_frame})\" -vframes 1";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
        }
    }

    private Task? ImageUpdateTask;
    private bool loop = false;

    //button start
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loop = true;
        ImageUpdateTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (loop)
            {
                RunProcessOnce();
                pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("output.jpg");
                }));
                MessageBox.Show(master_frame.ToString()); // Runs multiple times one by one
                master_frame++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).